# How can I improve SFTP transfer times between a Windows 7 PC and an Android phone?

Tags: windows-7, download, speed, sftp, upload

I have set up a home SFTP server using CoreFTP. When I transfer files from my Android phone to a PC, I get really slow speeds (1-1.5 MBps) as compared to SHAREit or Xender (Up-to 10 MBps). Why is it so? And can I do anything to improve the SFTP speed?

It’s more convenient to use the server as compared to the sharing apps. I use a [D-Link N300 Cloud Router](http://us.dlink.com/products/connect/wireless-n300-cloud-router/), a Windows 7 PC and a Sony Xperia L (C2104).

Comment: Sounds like either the SFTP client on the phone is slow, or your connection is slow. Have you tried using a different SFTP app? I suppose it's possible that either the phone's storage or the PC's storage is that slow, but I doubt it.

Comment: @CBHacking But, as I've mentioned, I've used the same mobile and PC to transfer files using SHAREit. And it gives much faster speeds. So, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the storage or hardware. And, can you suggest any other free SFTP solution?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize SHAREIt was another phone<->PC utility. I don't use Android and am not available with the SSH/SFTP apps available for it, sorry. SFTP does have higher overhead than many copy utilities, since it encrypts everything, but the transfer speed should bottleneck on the I/O, not on the crypto; even pure-software TLS on a phone CPU is faster than that.